# jquery slidedown and hide issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please check this code:

```
 var data = $(".others-involved-div-wrapper-tobe-copied").html();
 data = '<div class="others-involved-div-wrapper" >'+data+'</div>';
 $(".others-involved-div-wrapper:last").after(data).slideDown("slow");
 if ($(".others-involved-div-wrapper").length > 1){
     $(".others-involved-div-wrapper:last .delete-more-others-involved").show();
 }
```

Here the slideDown effect is not working.
The data is not seen if I do display none in div

```
data = '<div class="others-involved-div-wrapper" style="display:none;" >'+data+'</div>';
```

If  I'm doing `data  = data.hide();` ,Its showing error hide is not a function.

I just need slidedown effect when that data value is appended.

Comment: Try : `$(".others-involved-div-wrapper:last").after(data);` Then `$(".others-involved-div-wrapper:last").slideDown("slow");`

Comment: @sdespont Still no effect :(

Comment: Why are you assigning two separate instances to the data variable?

Comment: And : `$(".others-involved-div-wrapper:last").after(data);` Then `$(".others-involved-div-wrapper").each(function(){$(this).slideDown("slow");});`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also refactor your code using a jQuery element creation construct.

```
$("<div/>", {
    "class": "others-involved-div-wrapper",
    "html": $(".others-involved-div-wrapper-tobe-copied").html()
}).hide().insertAfter("div:last").slideDown("slow");
```

Or, even use `.clone()`.

```
$(".others-involved-div-wrapper-tobe-copied")
.clone()
.toggleClass("others-involved-div-wrapper-tobe-copied others-involved-div-wrapper")
.hide()
.insertAfter(".others-involved-div-wrapper:last")
.slideDown("slow");
```

Answer (score 2):

> data = data.hide()
>   wont work because it is just HTML text and not a jquery object.

Check if

```
$(".others-involved-div-wrapper:last").after(data)
```

returns a jquert object. That might be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Unless there is a reason that I'm unaware of, it appears that you are confusing jQuery with your variable assignments. Perhaps this might work for you:

```
 var content = $(".others-involved-div-wrapper-tobe-copied").html(),
     data = '<div class="others-involved-div-wrapper" >'+ content +'</div>';

 $(".others-involved-div-wrapper:last").after(data).slideDown("slow");

 if ($(".others-involved-div-wrapper").length > 1){

     $(".others-involved-div-wrapper:last .delete-more-others-involved").show();

 }
```

And @GautamJeyaraman is right, you can't apply a jquery method to a non jQuery object.